# VBA how to output class module (object) from function to excel worksheet, and using that output as input for another function?

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have 2 class modules named 'myFruits':

```
Public nApples As Integer
Public nOranges As Integer
```

and 'fruitPrice':

```
Public Apple As Double
Public Orange As Double
```

I want to write 3 functions/modules 'showFruits', 'showPrice' and 'getValue' which I can call in excel worksheet, with inputs and outputs below, and able to display/print in the excel sheet in this manner: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc506.jpg

The first two functions' outputs (class objects) will be inputs for the third function, 'getValue', which returns the value of number of fruits * fruit price.

I'm familiar with Python but new to VBA, and I'm having trouble finding resources that do exactly this. Any help is appreciated!

This is my attempt so far:

1.

```
Function showFruits(nApples As Integer, nOranges As Integer) As myFruits

    Set showFruits = New myFruits

    showFruits.nApples = nApples
    showFruits.nOranges = nOranges

    'How to print above variables in excel?
    'How to use the output object of this function as input for another function in excel?

End Function
```

2. 

```
Function showPrice(pApple As Double, pOrange As Double) As fruitPrice

    Set showPrice = New fruitPrice

    showPrice.Apple = pApples
    showPrice.Orange = pOranges

    'How to print above variables in excel?
    'How to use the output object of this function as input for another function in excel?

End Function
```

3. 

```
Function getValue(showFruits As myFruit, showPrice As fruitPrice)

    'How to pass the output objects as input to this function in excel?

    Dim total As Double
    total = showFruits.nApples * showPrice.Apple + showFruits.nOranges * showPrice.Orange
    getValue = total

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot going on here, but I'm not sure I understand why you're using a Class Module at all.

For the function piece, check out documentation on [Creating custom functions in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f). I've always called these [User Defined Functions](https://trumpexcel.com/user-defined-function-vba/), so you might find some luck searching for that as well.

Something like this to get started:

```vb
Function showFruits(nApples) As String

'How to print above variables in excel?
'Simply assign a value/output/something to your function

showFruits = "Apples: " & nApples

End Function
```